# <div> padding affecting <p> margin

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I have a design created using `html` and `css` and have come across an issue that confuses me.

The `div` tag that surrounds my `p` tag has a `padding` of `0 20px;`.  The `p` tag is either as default (according to the `font-size`) or is stated in the `css`.

**The issue:** The `margin` of the `p` tag is not shown *unless* there is a `padding` of at least `1px` in the surrounding `div`.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <p>Why hello there Sir!</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    padding:0 20px;
    /* padding:1px 20px; */
    /* fixes the issue but adds an extra pixel, which I don't want */
    background:#ccc;
}
p {
    margin:20px 0;
}
```

Here's a working example (with a button fixing the issue): http://jsfiddle.net/hrRNu/

I would really like this to work without any padding there at all.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
div {
    background:#ccc;
    padding:0 20px;
}
p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:20px 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Why is this needed though?

Comment: @Titanium Using `padding:20px 0;` alone on `p` also works. This is because the `margin` on `p` does not increase the height of the `div`. It simply pushes it down.

Answer (score 5):

This is what is called "collapsing margins" and is normal behavior. See more here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Setting p – a natural block level element – as `inline-block` is not really an appropriate "fix" for your problem.

You could instead set the margin to the div itself.